# search names in database in order and not unique

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wanted to be able to search a name/address/number in my database. I was able to do a unique number search but if the data is not unique then it is hard. I am using MySQL/XAMPP fyi.

this are my attempts in making this by starting to make a form

```
echo "<div style='text-align:right'>
            <form action='DisplayThisName.php' method='POST'>
            <Table border='0' align='right'>
            <tr>
                <td ><font size='-3'>Name Search</font></td>
                <td rowspan =2><input type='hidden' name='chck' id='chck' value='1'><input name='SUBMIT' type='SUBMIT' id='SUBMIT' value='Search!'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name='FNAME' type='text' id='FNAME'></td>
            </tr>
            </table><br>
            </FORM> </div>";
```

then I check the data that was pass through here

```
    <?php
        print "<center><H2>Display User</H2></center>";
        $ID_CHECK = clean($_POST['chck']);
        if($ID_CHECK == '1')
            $FNAME   = clean($_POST['FNAME']);
        else
            $FNAME   = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = $FNAME" );
        if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            print "<BR>There is no such user with the user number of $FNAME <BR><A HREF ='DisplayUserwLink.php'>Go Back</A>";
            exit();
        }
        else {
            $row_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    ?>

lastly I will show it here

<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=5 CELLSPACING=5>
            <TR>
                <TD>User No</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ID_NO" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['ID_NO']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Last Name</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="LNAME" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['LNAME']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>First Name</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="FNAME" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['FNAME']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Middle Name</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="MNAME" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['MNAME']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Date</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="DATE" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['DATE']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Age</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="AGE" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['AGE']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Sex</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="SEX" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['SEX']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Status</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="STATUS" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['STATUS']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Tel.#</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TEL_NO" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['TEL_NO']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Address</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ADDRESS" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['ADDRESS']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Occupation</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="OCCUPATION" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['OCCUPATION']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Referred by</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="REFERRED_BY" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['REFERRED_BY']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Is Color-Blind?</TD>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="itResult" VALUE="<?php print "{$row_array['itResult']}" ?>" READONLY></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
```

the clean.php is this

```
<?php
    function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }
?>
```

i get an error at this part when checking the data

```
 if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
```

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

what am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change your php code from this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = $FNAME" );
if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
```

to this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = $FNAME";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_error())
{
    die(mysql_error() .": $sql");
}
if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
```

Now when your sql query fails, you will have some idea why. You can copy/paste the sql statement into the Mysql Monitor at a shell prompt and run the query there.

Your query probably fails because $FNAME is empty, and you are not quoting it in your $sql statement as you should.

So the query given to mysql is in error like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = ;
```

instead of being on that has no error and finds no rows, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = '';
```

Now you see your php would be better like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = '$FNAME'";
```

and better still

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info 
        WHERE FNAME = '". mysql_real_escape_string($FNAME)."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

This mysql query getting failed

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = $FNAME" )
```

change it to

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE FNAME = '$FNAME'" )
```

and consider the using `mysql_error()`

Comment: I think the ending needs to be  FNAME = ' ".$FNAME."'"

Comment: hey it worked! its hard to find these kind of errors.. i think i have to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your query. your query returning empty value.